# CSS3 Animation is shaking

Tags: html, css, animation

I am currently building an interactive map, I have various animated elements that I am currently working through. I have noticed however, that the animations are jumping/shaking slightly whilst they are animating.

You can see my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/KKppxZe)

Does anyone have any ideas why they are slightly shaking? I have checked all browsers, the shaking is minimal but still having an effect!

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html,
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.desk-map {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animations>div {
  position: absolute;
}

.balloon-1 {
  width: 4.5%;
  height: 9%;
  background-image: url("https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/balloon-1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 12%;
  top: 14%;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: balloon1 14s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes balloon1 {
  0% {
    left: 12%;
    top: 14%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 12%;
    top: 2.5%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 12%;
    top: 14%;
  }
}

.balloon-2 {
  width: 4.5%;
  height: 9%;
  background-image: url("https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/balloon-2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 6.5%;
  top: 21%;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: balloon2 14s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes balloon2 {
  0% {
    left: 6.5%;
    top: 21%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 6.5%;
    top: 15%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 6.5%;
    top: 21%;
  }
}

.car-1 {
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 1.5%;
  background-image: url(https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/car-1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 32.25%;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: car1 30s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes car1 {
  0% {
    right: 22%;
    bottom: 32.25%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 57.25%;
    bottom: -0.4%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="map">
    <div class="desk-map">
      <img src="https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/map.png" />

      <div class="animations">
        <div class="balloon-1"></div>
        <div class="balloon-2"></div>

        <div class="car-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try running it on live server, in JavaScript there is a package called live-server

Answer (score 0):

This is because the distance to cover by balloon's and the time for animation is not in sync.

eg. you have to travel 100 km and you have 100 days to cover that distance, then your movement will be like slow moving ( stop and move ). If you have to cover 100 km and you have 10 min, then your movement will be like running ( fast ). You have to adjust those timings in the balloon movement.

You please replace the css with the updated css below and check

Also please check the snippet, adjust the animation time to see the effect. You can fix a duration which you think is smooth for your need.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

      html,
      body {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        outline: 0;
      }

      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }

      .map-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .map {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .desk-map {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*         background-image: url("background-image: uri('https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/map.png"); */
        background-color: #cccccc;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      .animations>div {
        position: absolute;
      }


      .balloon-1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/balloon-1.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        left: 20%;
        top: 5%;
        z-index: 1;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        perspective: 1000;
        animation: balloon1 20s infinite linear;
      }

      @keyframes balloon1 {
        0% {
          transform: translateY(100%);
        }

        50% {
          transform: translateY(0)
        }

        100% {
          transform: translateY(100%)
        }
      }

      .balloon-2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/balloon-2.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        left: 6.5%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        perspective: 1000;
        animation: balloon2 30s infinite linear;
        animation-delay: .5s;
      }

      @keyframes balloon2 {
        0% {
          transform: translateY(100%)
        }

        50% {
          transform: translateY(0)
        }

        100% {
          transform: translateY(100%)
        }
      }

      .car-1 {
            width: 6%;
          height: 10%;
        background-image: url(https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/car-1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 1;
       animation: car1 10s infinite linear;
       animation-delay: 1s;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      }

      @keyframes car1 {
         0% {
    right: 22%;
    bottom: 32.25%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 57.25%;
    bottom: -0.4%;
  }
      }
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
        <div class="map">
          <div class="desk-map">
            <img src="https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/map/map.png" />

            <div class="animations">
              <div class="balloon-1"></div>
              <div class="balloon-2"></div>

              <div class="car-1"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi Akhil, so I see you updated the animation to 8s. But what if we want this as 20s? Why would this shake, surely this should still run smoothy? Thanks!

Comment: @Brad the thing is it has a  short distance to travel in 20 sec, I think thats why its shaking.

Comment: @Brad instead of `top` you should try `transform: translateY(100px)`

Comment: Hi Akhil, could you give me an example of using the above? I tried on codepen but wasnt seeing the correct results

Comment: Hi Akil, if I use px this wont be fully responsive? Could you please advise?

Comment: I can use the following CSS "transform: translate(120%, 420%);" to target the position but is the percentages too high here? As sometimes I need to use "transform: translate(420%, 860%);" thank you!

Comment: I see, however I need the balloons in a certain position on the site. Can I use transform: translate(120%, 420%);? Or are the percentages too high?

Comment: @Brad you can try the fiddle I just created. make a copy of the fiddle and try :)

Comment: Yes its not working, really frustrating people saying to do transform:translate(-100%, -100%); for it to move to bottom right of screen, however mine wont! Dont understand why

Comment: @Brad the animation is working, right. whats the new issue here